# Counting with cards

Tags: combinatorics, card-games

Suppose you draw five cards from a deck of 52 cards. What is the probability of getting three cards (but not four cards) of one kind (all of their suits are same)?

Basically, it seems intuitively to me that $\frac{C(13,3)C(4,1)C(48,1)}{C(52,5)}$ is the correct answer, since we pick arbitrarily $5$ from $52$ cards, 3 cards of same kind from each $13$ possibilities, multiplying it with $4$ and choosing remaining card.

For the sake of completeness, 2 2 2 K 6 and 2 2 2 K K are each three cards but 2 2 2 2 K is not.

Comment: This is not clear.  Are you computing the probability of getting three of a kind under the standard rules of poker?  If so, you must exclude full houses (though your post does not indicate that you are doing that).  Following the poker rules, the number of three of a kind hands is $\binom {13}1\times \binom {4}1\times \binom {12}2\times \binom 41^2$.  Or did you mean something else?

Comment: @lulu Three of a kind means they are the same types: either all are diamonds, or heart and etc. Thanks in advance for this question!

Comment: No, it does not.  Three of a kind means three of the same rank ($2's$, $3's$, and so on), and then two mismatched cards to fill out that hand.  Thus $9\spadesuit\,9\clubsuit\,9\heartsuit\,K\diamondsuit\,3\clubsuit$ is an example.

Comment: [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poker_probability) is a link which gives examples of each of the standard types of poker hands and computes the probabilities of each.

Comment: If you meant that you want three cards of a single suit and the other two mismatched (in suits) with no attention to the ranks, then the number of good hands is $\binom 41\times \binom {13}3\times \binom 32\times \binom {13}1^2$.  But, as with the three of a kind, you must specify whether or not you care if the "extra two" cards share the same suit or not.  In my calculation I assumed that they had to have different suits (different from each other and different from the common suit of the triplet).

Comment: So in the problem, for the 3 of a kind, is the rank (number) the same, or the suit (category/type) the same?

Comment: @Lulu yes, I agree on your first answer. Then, why the following reply also states that answer is different if we refer to original meaning of "three of a kind"?

Comment: the confusion, such as it is, arises from the fact that, under the standard rules of poker, a Full House is $\textit{not}$ an example of Three of a kind.  Similarly a straight flush is neither a straight nor a flush, though of course it appears to be both.  This ambiguity causes a lot of confusion so it's always a good idea to define your concepts precisely.

Comment: @Lulu I edited the post, thanks for your feedback

Comment: To be precise:  $9\spadesuit \, 9\diamondsuit\,9\heartsuit \,K\spadesuit\,K\clubsuit$ is $\textit{not}$ a three of a kind.  It is a Full House.

Comment: Just to say:  your edit is still not clear.  You specifically refer to  three cards for which "all of their suits are the same".  That means something like  $9\spadesuit \, 10\spadesuit \,K\spadesuit\,Q\clubsuit\,2\diamondsuit$. That's fine, if that's what you want, though again you ought to specify whether you require the other two cards to have different suits (from each other) or not.

Comment: @Lulu I am allowing the example $222KK$

Comment: Once again, that example refers to rank, not to suit.  We're going in circles here...I think you need to clarify, in your mind, what it is you are trying to ask.

Comment: @lulu I am really sorry for not such a detailed clarification. This question was asked by my professor, and he only elaborated on example I provided on the new post. It seems he counted full houses as well, since my answer for "three of a kind" turned to be wrong, and the correct answer became $C(13,1)C(4,3)C(48,2)$

Comment: I really stress out that professor did not provide sufficient examples if he talked about "three of a kind" with only giving examples I provided in the new post. What else did he need to clarify? I can directly tell him so that he would understand his mistake!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116307/discussion-between-rasul-rza24-and-lulu).

Comment: I know that. What needed I to tell you in advance so that it could be very precise?

Comment: The confusion is in the fact that you persistently refer to "suits" but all your examples concern "ranks".  That's what you need to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

"Three of a kind" in card problems usually means three of the same value (Ace, King, Queen, etc.) rather than three of the same suit.  The OP, however, has parenthetically explained that they mean three of the same suit. Given that interpretation, $C(13,3)C(4,1)$ does describe the number of ways of choosing those three cards. But it remains to choose *two* more cards, not just one, and they must come from one of the other three suits (since the OP explains parenthetically that there are to be *exactly* three, not four), so the final multiplicative factor should be $C(39,2)$, not $C(48,1)$. The probability is thus

$$C(13,3)C(4,1)C(39,2)\over C(52,5)$$

Just for completeness, if "three of kind" is given its usual meaning, the numerator for the probability is $C(13,1)C(4,3)C(48,2)$. I.e., choose the value for the three of a kind, then choose three of the four cards of that value, and finally choose two cards from the remaining cards of the other values.

Comment: Why the answer is $C(13,1)C(4,3)C(48,2)$, given the usual meaning of "three of a kind"?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poker_probability According to this link, and the following explanation, the answer seems to be (# $3$ of a kind) = $C(13, 1) * C(4, 3) * C(12, 2) * C(4, 1) * C(4, 1) = 13 * 4 * 66 * 4 * 4 = 54,912$

Comment: A three-of-a-kind is three cards showing the same number plus two cards that do not form a pair or create a four-of-a-kind. If we order the 5-card hand with the three-of-a-kind first, we have C(13, 1) choices for the number showing on the first three cards. Since we will have three out of four suits, we have C(4, 3) = 4 ways to choose the suits. The remaining two cards must show different numbers than the four-of-a kind and each other. There are C(12, 2) choices for these numbers. The last two cards may have any of the four suits, however.

Comment: I also edited the original post. Why then, the answer is not $54,912$?

Comment: @rasul_rza24, yes, you are quite right, in *poker* "three of a kind" means a hand where the other two cards don't form a pair (which would be called a "full house"). I was allowing for a more relaxed understanding in which you don't care what the other two cards are, as they're different from the ones that give you the three of one kind. I see from your edit that that's what you meant too, since you are allowing 222KK. So my "just for completeness" answer is correct: The final two cards are simply drawn from the remaining $48$.

Comment: So, does it mean my answer 54, 912 is correct?

Comment: @rasul_rza24, no, $C(13,1)C(4,3)C(48,4)$ is correct, if you are counting "full houses" as examples of hands with three (but not four) of one kind.

Comment: Just a correction/clarification to my previous, long comment: "as they're different" was meant to be "as long as they're different."